# Function reuse for Mongoose Update or Query

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am new to nodejs, mongoDB and I'm writing an application that manipulates data from multiple collections in mongoDB with unrelated data. Is there a way to avoid writing CRUD functions for every model or collection I have? I just want to write one function of each CRUD operation and reuse the same function for the different collections or models.

I have this in my *crudFunctions.js*

```
     var mongoose = require('mongoose');
     var records = mongoose.model('testCollection');

     exports.listAllRecords = function (req, res) {

     records.find(function (err, docs) {
     if (err) throw err;
     res.json(docs);
      });
```

In my *routes.js*

```
      module.exports = function(app){
      var crud = require('../controllers/crudFunctions');

      app.route('/api/data')
      .get(crud.listAllRecords)
      };
```

The above code works fine for just one model ***records*** but I want to have different models for the different collections in my DB. The question is, how can I use something like (it may not be correct but i hope you understand the question), in my ***routes.js***:

```
     module.exports = function(app){
     var crud = require('../controllers/crudFunctions');

     app.route('/api/data')
     .get(crud.customFunction(function(myModel, results)
      {
       myModel = model;
       console.log(reults)
      })
```

Where:
   **myModel** is the name of one of my differet models I want to do some CRUD and
   **results** is the response with the document from db in case I'm doing ***find()*** query.

Comment: What you are looking for is already implemented with ["Instance Methods"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) and ["Static Methods"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics)